# LiDAR data for Palawan (Philippines)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, images

Are there any public or private sources of LIDAR data for the San Paul river in Palawan (Philippines)? Searching online did not lead me to any sources, and I am unsure how the commercial world of LIDAR works. I'm speleo and I would like to know this area better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Philippine government with the aid of the UN has been doing LiDAR mapping of the major river basins. Here's a press release:

It appears the effort is part of the Philippines DREAM project (for disaster risk/assessment):

https://www.dream.upd.edu.ph/

https://www.facebook.com/DREAMLIDAR

The University of the Philippines Los Banos has a page for LiDAR mapping of the Palawan province.

http://phil-lidar.uplb.edu.ph/index.php/study-sites/palawan

fyi> I see you posted the same question on GIS stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, I might need that data for scientific research, of my friends have already visited cave and have made the survey delll'interno the cave of St. Paul river. I asked the same question about GIS StackExchange, I now have an answer and I can delete it.
http://www.laventa.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=57:palawan&catid=41:palawan&Itemid=58&lang=en
Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't think you need to delete the question on GIS. Just add a comment to your question pointing back to this answer.

Comment: You're right. I've Done .

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode
`The Philippine government with the aid of the UN has been doing LiDAR mapping of the major river basins`

 AFAK, the UN is not involved in the DREAM project. It's purely funded by the national government.

https://dream.upd.edu.ph/about-us/

Or is the UN offering technical help? A reference would be nice :)